# Any performance difference between window.myObject.myProperty and myObject.myProperty

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global

When creating a global object in a `<script>` tag in HTML, it's my understanding that the global object is put into the DOM object `window`.  But to reference the global object, you don't need to explicitly use `window.` as a prefix.

```
<script>
  myGlobalObject = {};
  myGlobalObject.myProperty = "testing";
  window.myGlobalObject.myProperty2 = "testing2";

  //get value from global
  var retrievedValue = myGlobalObject.myProperty;
  //get another value
  var anotherVal = window.myGlobalObject.myProperty2;
</script>
```

I think that I also read somewhere that the browser will first look through the window object, and it will match anything with the same name?  So, I guess using `window.` becomes immaterial?  Just looking for a definitive clarification.  Obviously, it's more typing to add `window.` to everything.  Is there any downside to NOT prefixing a global object with `window.`?

Comment: "the browser will first look through the window object" I think it's the inverse, beginning by the more scoped and then going back to the window. But regarding performances, I think it's near 0 difference.

Comment: @Kaiido is correct, resolution works from the innermost scope to the outermost. But in a case like this, this is absolutely negligible … when you have multiple nested scopes, then you can start thinking about it again.